# Python Bokeh: Rect not rendering with another glyph

Tags: python, bokeh, rect, glyph

Below I have some code for a circle and rectangle on a plot.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d
from bokeh.resources import settings
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.io import export_svg



def ExScore(Xax,Yax):

  #X and Y axes
  xfactors = ['-100', '0', '100', '200', '300', '400' ]
  yfactors = ['-100', '-85', '-50', '50', '200', '400']

  #Coordinates for the heatmap rectangles. It should be a grid of 3 across and 5 high
  xr = ['-16.67','-16.67','-16.67','-16.67','-16.67','249.99','249.99','249.99','249.99','249.99','416.65','416.65','416.65','416.65','416.65']
  yr = ['-92.5','-67.5','0','125','300','-92.5','-67.5','0','125','300','-92.5','-67.5','0','125','300']

  #Colors for the rectangles
  colors = [
  '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
  '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
  '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
  '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
  '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
  ]

  #Creating figure
  p = figure(title="ExampleHeatMap", tools="hover", toolbar_location=None,
       x_range=xfactors, y_range=yfactors, plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500)

  #Making axes invisible
  p.xgrid.visible = False
  p.ygrid.visible = False

  #Rendering rectangles that won't show
  p.rect(xr,yr, fill_color=colors, line_color='white', width=100, height=100, fill_alpha=1.0)

  #Rendering circle that does show
  f1 = p.circle(Xax, Yax, size=10, color='#000000', fill_alpha=1.0)

  #Adding legend
  legend = Legend(items=[
      ("Example" , [f1])
  ])
  p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

  show(p)


x = []
y = []

x.append('100')

y.append('50')

ExScore(x,y)
```

I have gone through some of the other questions here (correcting the number of coordinates and accuracy, adjusting width/height/color, trying to use output_notebook, ensuring plot points and data are uniform [I.e strings], etc. ). No matter what change I make, I can't get the heatmap to render beneath the circle (or at all), rendering a graph like below:

[image]

I've tried testing as I know how, but for whatever reason the rect won't render. It's probably something simple that I'm missing, but trying out other solutions in SO hasn't helped yet. I'm using bokeh version 2.4.2. If someone could provide direction, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: Categoical (string) factors are *not numeric*. Categorical ranges define a *discrete* set of coordinates. With `xfactors = ['-100', '0', '100', '200', '300', '400' ]` then those values and literally *only those values* are valid coordinates for the categorical range. Something like `'-16.67'` is meaningless for that categorical range. It seems like you need/want to use standard numercial range with numerical `start` and `end`.

Comment: Thank you @bigreddot. This is exactly what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please  check if this is what you want:

```
def ExScore(Xax,Yax):
    xfactors = [-100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0]
    yfactors = [-100.0, -85.0, -50.0, 50.0, 200.0, 400.0]

    #Coordinates for the heatmap rectangles. It should be a grid of 3 across and 5 high
    xr = [-16.67, -16.67, -16.67, -16.67, -16.67, 249.99, 249.99, 249.99, 249.99, 249.99, 416.65, 416.65, 416.65, 416.65, 416.65]
    yr = [-92.5, -67.5, 0.0, 125.0, 300.0, -92.5, -67.5, 0.0, 125.0, 300.0, -92.5, -67.5, 0.0, 125.0, 300.0]

    #Colors for the rectangles
    colors = [
    '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
    '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
    '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
    '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
    '#2ECC71','#82E0AA','#D5F5E3',
    ]

    #Creating figure
    p = figure(title="ExampleHeatMap", tools="hover", toolbar_location=None,
       plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500)

    #Making axes invisible
    p.xgrid.visible = False
    p.ygrid.visible = False

    #Rendering rectangles that won't show
    p.rect(xr,yr, fill_color=colors, line_color='white', width=100, height=100, fill_alpha=1.0)

    #Rendering circle that does show
    f1 = p.circle(Xax, Yax, size=10, color='#000000', fill_alpha=1.0)

    #Adding legend
    legend = Legend(items=[
      ("Example" , [f1])
    ])
    p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

    show(p)
```

The genereated figure looks like this:
[image: Heatmap]

Comment: This answer and bigreddot above answered my query. Thank you!